# Avoid overlaying of connections and elements in jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jsplumb

I'm using [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/jquery.html) to create connection between elements in the page and I'm having troubles because the created connections overlay some elements on the site.

My connections are created dynamically so I can not predict the way they should look. I just want to avoid overlapping when necessary.

I've changed the `z-index` property of the overlayed elements and the connection is showed behind them.

[image]

However, what I'm looking for is to create the connection in a way that it doesn't goes through those elements in my site.

I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

Is that possible with jsPlumb? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you reproduce your code in jsFiddle?

Comment: @PruthviBharadwaj here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/S7Mk6/1/

Comment: @PruthviBharadwaj Can you please verify jsFiddle? its not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ADi Updated answer with FIddle link.

Comment: @PruthviBharadwaj Do you know how to make the arrows work?? I want the UI to be like this. http://jsfiddle.net/qn1rjrj9/. Can you please update your link with arrow like structure. I tried a lot but its not coming.

Comment: @PruthviBharadwaj fiddle is not working can you update fiddle again plzz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with `anchor` option(**[SOURCE](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/anchors#static)**). For your requirement set `anchor:Top`. Example:

```
jsPlumb.connect({...., anchor:"Top", ... });
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/S7Mk6/13/)

Comment: The anchors are generated dynamically so I can not predict how the connection should look like and where the connections should connect each box.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/S7Mk6/1/ I'm also having trouble with the arrow, (the overlay), but that's another topic.

Comment: @Alvaro So how do you position your elements? I think you need to work on elements position in this case!

Comment: The elements are static. Defined by CSS. The connections between them will be dynamically defined by a configuration file by the user. (defining origin and destination)

Comment: @Alvaro You can't change the path of connections in jsPlumb so you need to take care of initial elements position. Try to make use of different connectors while experimenting with `stub` value.

Answer (score 0):

You could add connection points between the element in order to gain better control over the connections path (although this would still require handling the logic of positioning these points).
Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/S7Mk6/4/):

```
ConnectBoxes($("#box1"), $("#box3"));

function ConnectBoxes(sourceDiv, targetDiv) {
    var connectionPointTop = targetDiv.position().top + targetDiv.height() / 2;
    var connectionPointLeft = sourceDiv.position().left + sourceDiv.width() / 2
     var connectionPoint1 = AddConnectionPoint("connectionPoint1", connectionPointTop, connectionPointLeft);
    jsPlumb.connect($.extend({
    source: 'box1',
    target: 'connectionPoint1',
}, options));
    jsPlumb.connect($.extend({
    source: 'connectionPoint1',
    target: 'box3',
}, options));
}


function AddConnectionPoint(divID, top, left) {
    var connectionPoint = $("<div></div>").attr({id: divID}).addClass("ConnectionPoint").css({"left": left + "px", "top": top + "px"});
    $("#divMain").append(connectionPoint);
    return connectionPoint;
}

div.ConnectionPoint {
    border: 3px solid #F00;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
```